# Zabbix API search for two values in the same field

Tags: php, api, zabbix

I'm using Zabbix PHPAPI and I have a problem!

How can you find two values ​​in the same field? For example:

```
$items[$h]=$zbx->itemGet(array (
        'filter' => ['hostid' => $arr[$h]['hostid']],
        'output' => ['itemid', 'LASTVALUE', 'name', 'key_']
        'search' => ['key_' => 'system.cpu.util', 'key_'=>'system.cpu.util [all]'],
));
```

I took the test but it always considers the last parameter key_

Answer (score 3):

I also happen to this question recently.I make it this way.It's ok!

```
{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "hostids": hostid,
            "sortfield": "name",
            'search': {
                'key_': ['system.cpu.util[,user]','system.cpu.util[,system]', 'vm.memory.size'],
            },
            'searchByAny': True
        },
        "auth": "something your auth code",
        "id": 1
}
```

Comment: `searchByAny` worked for me to search for two different patterns using wildcards. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
{
      hostids: [10309, 10274],
      search: {
        key_: ['system.cpu.load[percpu,avg1]', 'vfs.fs.size[/,pfree]']
      },
      searchByAny: true,
      output: ['name', 'lastvalue', 'units', 'key_']
}
```

> **searchByAny** worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, if you create an associative array specifying multiple identical keys, only the last one is used. In your example, `['key_' => 'system.cpu.util', 'key_' => 'system.cpu.util[all]']` creates the same array as `['key_' => 'system.cpu.util[all]']` does. So one of the problems is that PHP syntax is not being used properly.

The same, however, would happen if you would format the request in JSON directly. For instance, if you would specify "params" field of the request as follows, it would also use the last value of "key_" that you specified ("system.cpu.util[,iowait]" in the example), because a JSON object cannot have duplicate keys either:

```
{
    "output": "extend",
    "hostids": "10001",
    "search": {
        "key_": "system.cpu.util[,user]",
        "key_": "system.cpu.util[,system]",
        "key_": "system.cpu.util[,iowait]"
    }
}
```

Answering your real question, one should use "filter" to search for exact values and "search" for inexact values. So in order to search for multiple exact keys with Zabbix API you need to use "filter" field and pass it an array with values, like so:

```
{
    "output": "extend",
    "hostids": "10001",
    "filter": {
        "key_": [
            "system.cpu.util[,user]",
            "system.cpu.util[,system]",
            "system.cpu.util[,iowait]"
        ]
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it is possible to use "search" field with wildcards, like this:

```
{
    "output": "extend",
    "hostids": "10001",
    "search": {
        "key_": "system.cpu.util[,*]"
    },
    "searchWildcardsEnabled": true
}
```

This might return more items than you need though, and you have to do further filtering on the client side.

Please see [item.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference/item/get) and [general "get" parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference_commentary#common_get_method_parameters) reference for more details.